# Flutter dropdown button with future builder

Tags: flutter

I'm create dynamic count of drop down button in flutter, but I can't set that selected values to each drop down in flutter.

```dart
return DropdownButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
  isExpanded: true,
  hint: Text("select color"),
  iconSize: 30,
  underline: SizedBox(),
  items: colorList.map((list) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(list),
      value: list,
    );
  }).toList(),
  value: itemTestList[index] == null ? 'no':itemTestList[index],
  onChanged: (val) {
  setState(() {
    itemTestList[index] =val;
  });
});
```

Comment: Declare ```String _selectedValue;``` Then in your dropdown value replace this ``_selectedValue`` instead of ``value: itemTestList[index] == null ? 'no':itemTestList[index],``. In your setState write ``_selectedValue = val``. Then print this value

Comment: when i try with one drop down your answer is correct, but at this time i have dynamic count of drop down , therefore when i apply this solution it get this error..

There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: RED. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

Comment: Does your itemTestList contains duplicate value's?

Comment: no, it hasn't duplicate value

Comment: But the meaning of your message says that the list contains duplicate value. ```There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: RED. Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value```